# From a sorted list<Integer>, given an unsorted subgroup, find the minimum value of the subgroup

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, backend

I'm setting up a new server in Java-11, and want to find the minimum value of a subgroup from a given sorted list.

And I would like to know what is the most performable way as possible to achieve this.

For example:
sortedList = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}

an unsorted subgroup = {13,6,3,12,2}

result = 2.

Edit: the sortedList is the values themselves

Important Note: the sorted list will relatively be small , between 0 to 200 items approximately.
But this computation ocurres for every user that joins the server more than once, so it must be optimized.

Background of what I've tried:

n = the sorted list size

m = subgrouped list size

1) created an empty integer list sizeOf(m) 
fetched all ***indexes*** of the subgrouped items from the sorted list.
into the new list O(m), performed a minimum search and found the result O(m-1).
Time complexity = O(m) + O(m-1) ~ 2*O(m)

Question: is this the best approach?

2) fetched all indexes of the subgrouped items from the sorted list. inserted them into a list sizeOf(n). [which means a list of n-m zeros + m integers in it]. 
O(1) for creating an empty list sizeOf(n)
O(m) for fetching all indexes & inserting them to the new list,

so far, O(m)+O(1)

Now I know that the first number which isn't zero from the left is my smallest index of my sorted list values.

Question: is there a way to get that first number from the left without iterating over n-m zeros?

note: At this point I'm questioning this approach since now I'm back to an n complexity , m will always be alot smaller than n.

in total, O(m)+O(1) + O(n-m)  ~  O(m) + O(n-m)  ~  O(n)

parsing the list to a string and using regex is much more expensive than option 1.

Show some code:
I'm still in the technical design stage of this problem so I think the examples I've given above are enough

Describe expected and actual results:
My expected result of this thread is to find the fastest way to acheive a result of a the minimum value of an unsorted subgrouped list from a sorted list.

Comment: Does the subgroup contain the indexes of the elements in the sorted list? Or the actual integer values taken from the sorted list? And does the result need to be a value or an index?

Comment: Given that you are pretty certain that the list will be small, big O becomes almost entirely useless. Something could be constant time but still dog slow compared to something O(N²). Write a solution, profile it, optimise until it reaches your performance goals, stop. The same as for literally every performance-driven task.

Comment: The sorted list is the values them selfs, editing that, & yeah michael thats my last resort, there's always something new to learn so I'm curious to see other opinions

Comment: I don't get it... The time complexity to "_to find the minimum value of a subgroup from a given sorted list." would simply be O(n). We don't have to care about the sorted list, the research only have to iterate each item in the provided subgroup to find which is the smaller. Did I miss something ?

Comment: You are indeed missing something, since n is already sorted, m is a list of indexes from n. Once you find the smallest index of m you then fetch it from n and you got a result faster than O(n)

Comment: To find the minimum of a small unordered list, you can't do much better than just looping over and keeping track of the minimum, which would also take O(m) for a list of size m. Being a subgroup could only help if it were ordered (at least in the worst/average case - in the best case you can stop if you've found the known minimum). If this is too slow, you have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you should try to *avoid* instead of *optimize* having to find the minimum of an unordered list.

Comment: Re your edit - "The sorted list is the values themselves" - I don't see how it could be anything else. What's more important is what is the *unsorted* list (the subgroup). You don't seem to specify that explicitly. It's important because if the unsorted subgroup contains the values themselves, then you can completely discard the sorted list and just work only on the subgroup.

Comment: Big-O ignores constant factors, so `2*O(m)` is equal to `O(m)`. Although `2*O(m)` and `O(m) + O(m-1)` are, at best, short-hand for more complex operations, since `O(m)` is actually a set of functions, not a number. If you want to talk about exact numbers, you shouldn't use big-O (you can instead count the exact number of some operation; for example, count comparisons and find that something takes `2m` comparisons).

Comment: The subgroup could never be the indexes since the sorted list can change in any given time, hence the subgroup must contain the actual integer values

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Dukeling, noted.

Comment: Then isn't the problem just a simple problem of finding the minimum value in the subgroup? Is there anything else to it? What relevance is the sorted list?

Comment: @Benma You're right that there's always something to learn, in this case though I think that "pick your fights" is what you'll probably end up learning